# Interview question Swift, incomprehensible syntax

Tags: ios, swift, syntax, nlp-question-answering

In the WWW I find interview question and one of them is:

What will be the output of the code snippet below:

```
class Kondana<T:Equatable> {
    var dictDataHolder = [String:T]()
    func add(value:T?,using key:String) -> T? {
         self.dictDataHolder[key] = value
         return value
    }
}
var fortOne = Kondana<String>()
let value = fortOne.
print(value)
```

Answers are:

```
a) British
b) nil
c) compile-time error
d) segmentation fault
```

I am run this code in Xcode and my output is:

```
__lldb_expr_21.Kondana<Swift.String>
```

Help me please understand what is going on step by step.
I have thoughts about what is going on but not sure about them.
What is Kondana class and why use the syntax like above, I know that is generic but not understand the output?

Comment: the code you posted isn't complete - this line is cut short `let value = fortOne.`

Comment: Can you more information about the interview which may clarify the answer people here could do ?

Comment: When you ran it, you put "let value = fortOne" instead of "let value = fortOne." and that printed a representation of what fortOne is - actually it should have given a syntax error at the . character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code posted, the correct answer is "compile-time error". As others have said, the line

```
let value = fortOne.
```

is truncated, and is therefore not legal.